# I can't find ModalBottomSheetLayout in material3 with jetpack compose?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-bottomsheetdialog, android-jetpack-compose-material3

## Update

We finally have BottomSheet in Material3 follow this ans [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75497791/11855060) 
Recently I created a project using `material3` with `jetpack compose` but when I tried to import `ModalBottomSheetLayout` but I couldn't find it. Is there any `alternate in material3` or not ?

In previous material version we do like :-

```
ModalBottomSheetLayout(sheetContent = ) {
        
    }
```

Comment: Just add sheetContent and it would be solved

Comment: You can find all the [Jetpack Compose Material 3 components here](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/material3/package-summary#ModalNavigationDrawer(kotlin.Function1,androidx.compose.ui.Modifier,androidx.compose.material3.DrawerState,kotlin.Boolean,androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Shape,androidx.compose.ui.unit.Dp,androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color,androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color,androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color,kotlin.Function0)).  `ModalBottomSheetLayout` is not yet ported to Material 3. Lot of components are still Work In Progress.

Answer (score 3):

[Maybe this will help you](https://androidx.tech/artifacts/compose.ui/ui/)
or you make do it

```
implementation 'androidx.compose.ui:ui:1.4.3'
implementation 'androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling'
implementation 'androidx.compose.ui:ui-graphics'
implementation 'androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling-preview'
implementation 'androidx.compose.material3:material3:1.1.1'
```

yes i just added the latest stable version

Comment: Maybe? You guess? You can improve your answer by providing proof (code and a screenshot) that it doesn't work for older versions of those packages and then proof that it works with the latest versions. The code would be something that uses ModalBottomSheetLayout. You don't have to provide all the files because every Android project is quite large but `app/build.gradle` and `MainActivity.kt` should suffice.

Comment: In my case it helped, I am using the latest version of android studio and components

Answer (score 2):

Based on [this package summary](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/material3/package-summary) it is not currently available in Material 3 for Compose.

Answer (score 0):

As in material3 version 1.1.0-alpha08 bottom sheet are experimental.
Original post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73594618/15739324

Answer (score -2):

Try using [`ModalBottomSheet`](https://www.composables.com/material3/modalbottomsheet) instead of `ModalBottomSheetLayout`.