# Jetpack Compose: BottomSheetLayout for Material3

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-compose-material3

I'm glad to see compose material3 has updated to beta release of 1.0.0-beta03. Though, I notice they still haven't added the implementation of something like a `BottomSheetLayout` or `BottomSheetScaffold`, which I'd like to apply in my material3 project.

Of course I can at least add the original `androidx.compose.material` library as a dependency, but it's what I hope to avoid since I've already moved to the brand new material3 UI.

I wonder is there any solution or workaround to realize almost the same effect as a `BottomSheetLayout` in current version of compose material3. Many thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to implement BottomSheet in Material 3 Jetpack Compose Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72518262/how-to-implement-bottomsheet-in-material-3-jetpack-compose-android)

Answer (score 0):

My solution to have `BottomSheetScaffold` in `material3` was to copy paste the implementation into my project and fixing all the dependencies to use material3 instead of material, or copy-pasting them as well if it wasn't possible. You can find my reply to a similar ticket along with the code over there:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/74175096/4373346

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

At time of writing, the [latest version of Compose Material 3](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/compose-material3#version_11_2) is 1.1.0-beta02, and as of [1.1.0-alpha06](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/compose-material3#1.1.0-alpha06) it has a `ModalBottomSheet` (they dropped the word "Layout").

Hopefully 1.1.0 comes out of beta soon! (and hopefully the standard bottom sheet gets added as well, whereas right now it only has the modal variant)