# How to make a expand tab row and it can overlap navigation bar in Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I'm new in Jetpack Compose and kotlin.
I want to make a custom scrollable tab row with an arrow icon and when I click this icon ,
the tap row will expand to show all taps and have a black block below this row ,this block can overlap navigation bar and if I click this block the expanded row will be collapse

(black block I meant like this photo
[black block example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uFwtJ.jpg)

I use Scaffold Composable and put this tap row in topbar but when I expand the row ,
Scaffold content and bottom bar will be push down,
if I put this row into Scaffold content when I expanded it the black block region can't overlap bottom bar .

I would appreciate it if someone can give me some suggestions,thx

(Sorry, I am foreigner,English and words may have some wrong

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to implement BottomSheet in Material 3 Jetpack Compose Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72518262/how-to-implement-bottomsheet-in-material-3-jetpack-compose-android)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.