# ModalBottomSheet in Material 3 for compose

Tags: android, kotlin, material-ui, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-compose-material3

I have switched from Material 2 to Material 3 in my android compose project :

I have this dependencie which is the latest stable one :

```
implementation ("androidx.compose.material3:material3:1.0.1")
```

As mention in the docs i should be able to import and use the ModalBottomSheet :

https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/material3/package-summary#ModalBottomSheet(kotlin.Function0,androidx.compose.ui.Modifier,androidx.compose.material3.SheetState,androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Shape,androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color,androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color,androidx.compose.ui.unit.Dp,androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color,kotlin.Function0,kotlin.Function1)

But i get unresolved reference when importing :

```
import androidx.compose.material3.ModalBottomSheet
```

All my others M3 components are fine.

**Can anyone help me on how I can import ModalBottomSheet without problem ?**

Comment: check out this, it seems something like your question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72518262/how-to-implement-bottomsheet-in-material-3-jetpack-compose-android

Comment: I have seen similar questions but it seems that google have added bottomSheet to the library since then because it is present in documentation with example..
I just dont get why my import (which is the same as the one in the sample) wont work..

Comment: Material3 implementation for the ModalBottomSheet was added to androidx.compose.material3:material3:1.1.0-alpha06. You won't find it the stable release yet.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to use Version 1.1.0-alpha06 of Material 3 as this is a very recent addition. Please have a look at the release notes [here](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/compose-material3#1.1.0-alpha06).

Answer (score 1):

You need to update the compose-bom to latest version in gradle module level file
like this:

```
implementation(platform("androidx.compose:compose-bom:2023.08.00"))
```

currently the latest version is `2023.08.00` when ever you want it change it according.